# Different learning curve of Adam between Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm currently changing my code from Keras to Tensorflow in order to use the new feature of quantized training in Tensorflow 1.10.0. However, I found out that the training process in Keras and Tensorflow shows very large difference when using Adam optimizer.

Here is the code for practice usage, which aims on the same purpose to train a "sin(10x)" function in Tensorflow and Keras way.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras.backend as K

KERAS = 'keras'
TENSORFLOW = 'tensorflow'


def create_model():
    ipt = Input([1])
    m = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(ipt)
    m = BatchNormalization()(m)
    m = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(m)
    m = BatchNormalization()(m)
    m = Dense(1)(m)
    return Model(ipt, m)


valX = np.expand_dims(np.linspace(-1, 1, 10000), 1)
valY = np.sin(valX * 10)
valY_ = {}

for phase in (KERAS, TENSORFLOW):
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.as_default()
    K.set_session(sess)

    model = create_model()

    if phase is KERAS:
        model.compile('adam', 'mean_squared_error')
    else:
        tensor_y_gt = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=model.output.get_shape().as_list())
        mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(model.output, tensor_y_gt)
        training_steps = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(mse)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for step in range(2000):
        X = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, [256, 1])
        Y = np.sin(X * 10)

        if phase is KERAS:
            loss = model.train_on_batch(X, Y)
        else:
            loss, _ = sess.run([mse, training_steps], feed_dict={model.input: X, tensor_y_gt: Y})

        if step % 100 == 0:
            print('%s, step#%d, loss=%.5f' % (phase, step, loss))

    valY_[phase] = model.predict(valX)[:, 0]

    sess.close()

valX = valX[:, 0]
valY = valY[:, 0]

plt.plot(valX, valY, 'r--', label='sin(10x)')
plt.plot(valX, valY_[KERAS], 'g-', label=KERAS)
plt.plot(valX, valY_[TENSORFLOW], 'b-', label=TENSORFLOW)
plt.legend(loc='best', ncol=1)
plt.show()
```

You can see the difference between the two:
plot of sin(10x)

[image]

Environment:

- tensorflow-gpu 1.10.0
- Keras 2.2.2

Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: are you sure that the hyperparameters for adam are the same in both cases?

Comment: I think they all have the same default parameters that follow those provided in the original paper.

Comment: Have you tried setting explicit random seeds? And are you *absolutely sure* that the values are the same?

Comment: i would print them out and make sure.

Comment: I tried to explicitly set the hyperparameters with "lr=.001, beta_1=.9, beta_2=.999, epsilon=1e-8" and ends up that tensorflow always converges better than keras. Though it seems good for those who's attempting to use TF instead of keras, but in my case I really need them to work in the same way to get the same result.

Comment: It can be an issue with session. Could you try a simple experiment: change order to `(TENSORFLOW, KERAS)`. Is still Keras worse?

Comment: I get worse result on Keras as well after change order to `(TENSORFLOW, KERAS)`.

Comment: Have the same issue, it seems that the initialisation of the weights i not the same in Keras and in Tensorlfow